# Simple Lex/Yacc syntax error matching a single question mark?

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I'm trying to build a calculator using lex/yacc where you can create an unlimited amount of variables and use them in calculations by using a linked list.

When you type "?", it should print out the contents of the linked list, it does do this, except afterwards, it gives me a: `syntax error` and ends my program.

The rest of the calculator works as expected, am I missing something?

Sample Output

```
-bash-4.1$ ./calc
a = 42
b = 21
c = a / b
?
num-syms: 5
    PHI => 1.61803
    PI => 3.14159
    a => 42
    b => 21
    c => 2
syntax error
-bash-4.1$
```

sym.h

```
#ifndef SYMTBL_H
#define SYMTBL_H

struct sym {
    int length;
    char * name;
    double value;
    struct sym *prev;
    struct sym *next;
};

struct sym * sym_p;
struct sym * sym_lookup(char *);
void sym_inventory();

#endif /* SYMTBL_H */
```

calc.l

```
%{
/*#include <math.h> */ 
#include "y.tab.h"
#include "sym.h"
%}

%%
"?" { sym_inventory(); }

([0-9]+|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?) {
    yylval.dval = atof(yytext);
    return NUMBER;
    }

[ \t] ; /* ignore whitespace */

[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]* {
    /* return symbol pointer */
    yylval.symptr = sym_lookup(yytext);
    return NAME;
    }

"$" { return 0; }
\n |
. { return yytext[0]; };
%%
int yywrap() { return 1; }
```

calc.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sym.h"
%}

%union {
    double dval;
    struct sym * symptr;
}

%token <symptr> NAME
%token <dval> NUMBER
%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc UMINUS

%type <dval> expression
%%
statement_list
    : statement '\n'
    | statement_list statement '\n'
    ;

statement
    : NAME '=' expression { 
        char *name = $1->name;
        if (strcmp(name, "PI") != 0 && strcmp(name, "PHI") != 0) {
            $1->value = $3; 
        } else {
            yyerror("assign to const"); 
        }
    }
    | expression { printf("= %g\n", $1); }
    ;

expression
    : expression '+' expression { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | expression '-' expression { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | expression '*' expression { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    | expression '/' expression { 
        if ($3 == 0) {
            yyerror("divide by zero");
        } else { 
            $$ = $1 / $3; 
        }
    }
    | '-' expression %prec UMINUS { $$ = -$2; }
    | '(' expression ')' { $$ = $2; }
    | NUMBER
    | NAME { $$ = $1->value; }
    ;

%%

struct sym * sym_lookup(char * s)
{
    if (sym_p == NULL) {
        sym_p = (struct sym *)malloc(sizeof(struct sym));
    }

    struct sym *original = sym_p;
    struct sym * sp = sym_p;

    if (sp->name == NULL) {
        struct sym *n = (struct sym *)malloc(sizeof(struct sym));
        n->name = "PI";
        n->value = 3.14159;
        n->next = NULL;
        sp->name = "PHI";
        sp->value = 1.61803;
        sp->next = n;
        sp->length = 2;
    }

    while (1) {
        if (sp->name == NULL) {
            sp->name = strdup(s);
            sp->next = NULL;
            return sp;
        } else if (strcmp(sp->name, s) == 0) {
            return sp;
        } else if (sp->next != NULL) {
            sp = sp->next;
        } else {
            struct sym *n = (struct sym *)malloc(sizeof(struct sym));
            n->name = strdup(s);
            sp = original;
            struct sym *old = NULL;

            while (1) {
                if (strcmp(sp->name, s) > 0) {
                    // new variable name comes before in ascii table
                    if (old == NULL) {
                        // new node insert at beginning of sym_p
                        n->next = original;
                        n->length = original->length;
                        sym_p = n;
                        original = sym_p;
                        sp = original;
                    } else {
                        // insert in middle and update links
                        old->next = n;
                        n->next = sp;
                        sp = original;
                    }
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (sp->next != NULL) { 
                        old = sp;
                        sp = sp->next;
                    } else {
                        sp->next = n;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            sp = original;
            sp->length++;
            return n;
        }
    }
}

void sym_inventory()
{
    struct sym * sp = sym_p;
    printf("num-syms: %d\n", sp->length);
    int i;
    int length = sp->length;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("\t%s => %g\n", sp->name, sp->value);
        sp = sp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: No; please don't destroy the question like you did (before I rolled back).  You should preserve enough of the grammar to allow the "empty line is not syntactically valid" diagnosis to be validated.  You could omit the symbol table code; at a pinch you could omit the lexical analyzer code, though it is simple enough to keep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

Your grammar doesn't recognize an empty line as a valid input.  When you type `?` followed by a newline, the newline is returned, and that isn't syntactically valid, hence the 'syntax error' report.

You could demonstrate by typing `?a + b` as an input, for example.

Note that your lexical analyzer processes the `?` without letting the parser know that it happened; the parser never sees the `?`.

#### Prodding to get enough information to make the question answerable

This adaptation of your Lex code shows that the lexical analyzer recognizes `?` as an input.  Your question doesn't show how the code is used, so there's not enough information for us to know what you're doing wrong.  You need to provide an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) so that you can get the relevant help.

```
%option noinput
%option nounput
%%
"?" { printf("Got a ?\n"); }

([0-9]+|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?) {
    printf("Number: %s\n", yytext);
    }

[ \t] { printf("Space: [%s]\n", yytext); }

[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]* {
    printf("Name: %s\n", yytext);
    }

"$" { printf("Dollar\n"); return 0; }
\n |
. { printf("Other: %c\n", yytext[0]); return yytext[0]; };
%%
int yywrap(void) { return 1; }

int main(void)
{
    while (yylex() != 0)
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run (shell prompt is `JL:` rather than `$` because one of the inputs is `$`):

```
JL: ./xy73
a b 23
Name: a
Space: [ ]
Name: b
Space: [ ]
Number: 23
Other: 

?
Got a ?
Other: 

=@%
Other: =
Other: @
Other: %
Other: 

$
Dollar
JL:
```

Comment: My apologies, I didn't want to post a wall of code, but I have posted the rest of the files, I'll add test cases to clarify as well

Comment: Yes, we don't want a wall of code (so thank you for not posting one), but we do need to be able to understand the problem — hence the need for an MCVE.  The file I posted is an MCVE; it can be compiled and run and it produces the output shown.  That demonstrates that the `yylex()` that is generated from your `.l` file can detect when you type a `?` and will run your `sym_inventory()` procedure when it does. Note that this will happen without returning to the parser. There was no grammar provided in the question originally, so there was no way to even guess how you got the syntax error message.

Comment: Thank you, I feel silly for having missed something so trivial. One last question, if you don't mind. What would be an appropriate place to initialize `PI/PHI` in the lex/yacc file so that I could run `?` immediately and have `PI/PHI` be listed (they get instantiated for the first time when a variable is stored if the linked list is `NULL`)

Comment: I would probably add PI and PHI to the symbol table in main, calling a function that would install a name and a value (I could imagine E being useful too, for example).

Answer (score 1):

The ? is followed by a newline which is returned as a character token, but your grammar only accepts a newline after a statement, which always starts with a NAME.

Comment: Actually, statements can start with a number or `-` or `(` too.  But the basic analysis is correct.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed the second alternative.  I should have said that the grammar doesn't allow an empty statement.